# Getting subset with same cordinates for different rasters using gdal.translate?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, rasterio, subset

I am a new into Python. I have processed 1000 NDVI rasters covering larger area. I need to burn those NDVI raster with Water mask. The water mask came for whole world I need to subset AOI and also want to subset the same AOI for the 1000 NDVI rasters. I want rows, column should be same so that I can burn with each other.

I have tried with https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/clipping-raster.html,
but it gives same rows column for all NDVI rasters but the no of columns and rows are changed when I subset the water mask with same cordinates.

I have tried with `gdal.translate()`

```
from osgeo import gdal

from shapely.geometry import box

minx, miny = 3.59, 41.14

maxx, maxy = 15.92, 49.27

bbox = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

ds = gdal.Open('/scratch/test_reproject/20030416_1335_ndvi_reprojected_proj4.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate('/scratch/test_reproject/output/20030416_1335_ndvi_reprojected_proj4_crop_gdal.tif', ds, projWin = [3.59, 41.14,  15.92, 49.27])
ds = None

from osgeo import gdal

from shapely.geometry import box
```